# textarea styling not submitted

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I've created a textarea editor without using any plugins, only with select fields for `font-family`, `font-size` and `font-color`.

It is working fine, but the thing is, what happen to all the effects I changed?

If I click submit it should save in database like:`<p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Chethan K</strong></p>` but this is not happening. Can anyone help me?

My code is :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="Post" action="<?php echo site_url('Maincntrl/texta'); ?>">
  <select id="clr">
    <option>-Color-</option>
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="gray">gray</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
  </select>
  <select id="fs">
    <option>-Font-</option>
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="impact">Impact</option>
    <option value="'ms comic sans'">MS Comic Sans</option>
  </select>
  <select id="size">
    <option>-Size-</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
  </select> <br>
  <textarea name="texta" rows=5 cols="34" class="changeMe"></textarea>
  <p class="changeMe" name="texta"> </p>
  <div id="btns" style="text-align: center ; ">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  $("#fs").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
  });

  $("#size").change(function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
  });

  $("#clr").change(function() {
    $('.changeMe').css("color", $(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @TakitIsy why would you have to draw my attention? If I knew a solution I would have provided it 2 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using `.css()` in your functions…

`.css()` adds styling **on** the element, but it doesn't add anything **inside**.

Here is a snippet where I added a consoling when you click on the <kbd>Save</kbd> button:

```js
$("#fs").change(function() {
  $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
});
$("#size").change(function() {
  $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
$("#clr").change(function() {
  $('.changeMe').css("color", $(this).val());
});

// TAKIT: Added this for testing purpose
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Value of textarea:\n  '" + $("textarea[name=texta]").val() + "'");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="Post" action="#">
  <select id="clr">
    <option>-Color-</option>
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="gray">gray</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
  </select>
  <select id="fs">
    <option>-Font-</option>
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="impact">Impact</option>
    <option value="'ms comic sans'">MS Comic Sans</option>
  </select>
  <select id="size">
    <option>-Size-</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
  </select> <br>
  <textarea name="texta" rows=5 cols="34" class="changeMe"></textarea>
  <p class="changeMe" name="texta"> </p>
  <!--div id="btns" style="text-align: center ; "-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
  <!--/div-->
</form>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Now, I think I understand why you used `<p class="changeMe" name="texta"> </p>`.
But the problem here is that you have two times the same `name="texta"`.

I made the following modifications:

- As you can only post values of form elements, I changed your `p` to an `input`. You could use `type=hidden` on it, but I used `disabled` so that we can see its value.
- Added a `class="selector"` and a "prop" attribute on your `select`s to simplify your code.
- Added `value=""` for the default options.

Here is the final snippet:

```js
$(".selector").change(function() {
  // Apply each select on the textarea
  $(".selector").each(function(i, elm) {
    $('.changeMe').css($(elm).attr('prop'), $(elm).val());
  });
  // Copy style of the textarea in our input using a span element
  $("[name=textstyle]").val($('.changeMe').attr('style'));
});

// TAKIT: Added this for testing purpose
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Submitted:");
  console.log("  textstyle: '" + $("[name=textstyle]").val() + "'");
  console.log("  texta: '" + $("[name=texta]").val() + "'");
});
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" method="Post" action="#">
  <select class="selector" prop="color">
    <option value="">-Color-</option>
    <option value="black">black</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="gray">gray</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
  </select>
  <select class="selector" prop="font-family">
    <option value="">-Font-</option>
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="impact">Impact</option>
    <option value="'ms comic sans'">MS Comic Sans</option>
  </select>
  <select class="selector" prop="font-size">
    <option value="">-Size-</option>
    <option value="5px">5</option>
    <option value="10px">10</option>
    <option value="15px">15</option>
    <option value="20px">20</option>
  </select> <br>
  <textarea name="texta" rows=5 cols="34" class="changeMe"></textarea>
  <!-- I propose you the following here: -->
  <br><input name="textstyle" disabled />
  <!--div id="btns" style="text-align: center ; "-->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
  <!--/div-->
</form>
```

Then, server-side, you get both `name`s and do your stuff.

Hope it helps.